# How to download roblox without being caught by auburn school district iPad 6th generation

Tags: ipad, ipados, mdm

How do you download roblox without it saying it is restricted

Answer (score 3):

There isn’t a good way to get around MDM restrictions, especially if you remove the profile, the MDM will have proof of when you made a change to the restrictions which would then have other repercussions.

1. Ask the staff or trainers if you can help them manage apps and test them.
2. Find out which MDM you are using in case they will let you (and authorize in writing) you can try to learn how to bypass this and let them know so you don’t get in trouble.
3. Stay curious and learning - this is more of a people problem than a technical problem, to be honest and your curiousity to learn the technology will be much enhanced when you learn the people skills necessary to renegotiate an agreement and gain consensus that you’re trustworthy and helping the overall mission to teach and secure and manage apps and devices.

Basically, reframe your participation as part of the solution and not another problem to be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Since you obviously can't at the moment, it's pretty safe to say that the Auburn School District is using some sort of MDM product ([Mobile Device Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management)).

This software allows the administrator(s) to lock down the devices per their policies.  Once a device is enrolled with MDM software, it must either be un-enrolled (like when being sold) or have the policy modified allowing software to be installed.

I also don't advise trying to circumvent the MDM software on the iPad.  You will likely be in violation of the Acceptable Use Policy you (and your parents) signed at the beginning of the school year.  It's much better to ask for permission in this case - see what flexibility they (the school administrators, not the network administrators) have.  If you make a strong enough case, they may work with you on easing restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the main page of a game on Roblox when you are connected to a WiFi connection, good, you are then able to simply click the green play button and then click 'Download and Install Roblox' and do what it says to do and you will have it downloaded and installed. It should automatically download and install Roblox Studio as well. But do not let anyone know that you have done this because if it is blocked then it obviously means that you are not allowed to have/install/download/use it.